# Зачем введены методы tryxxx с параметром out

Tags: c#

Собственно сабж.

```
int result = 0;
Int32.TryParse("10", out result);
if(result != 0)
DoSomething();
```

Т.е. мне нужно создать переменную, которая мне не нужна. По-мойму так проще:

```
if(Int32.TryParse("10") != null)
DoSomething();
```

Для этого методу TryParse нужно лишь возвращать int?. Однако, в фреймворке используется первый подход. Почему?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Во-первых, в забываете/не знаете, что метод TryParse (а не TryXXX кстати) возвращает bool, сообщающий вам о том, удалось ли преобразование. Метод, который возвращает полученное в результате преобразования значение, называется  Parse. Например:

```
int res = Int32.Parse("123");
```

Во-вторых, ваш пример

```
if(Int32.TryParse("10") != null)
```

неправилен. Как он, по-вашему, должен возвращать в одном случае int (value-type), а в другом null (явно указывающий на reference-type)?

Тем не менее, можно написать матод расширения, который поможет решить проблему неудобного синтаксиса:

```
namespace MyExtensions
{
    public static class ParseExtender 
    {
        public static int? ParseInt(this string source)
        {
            int res;
            return Int32.TryParse(source, out res) ? (int?)res : null;
        } 
    }
}
```

А если уж хотите и вовсе универсальности, то можете сделать вот так:

```
namespace MyExtensions
{
    public static T? RightParse<T>(this string input) where T : struct
    {
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));

        try
        {
            return (T?)converter.ConvertFromString(null,                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, input);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Использовать так:

```
Console.WriteLine("256".RightParse<int>() ?? -1);
Console.WriteLine("256.2".RightParse<double>() ?? -1);
Console.WriteLine("true".RightParse<bool>() ?? false);
```

Только не забудьте добавить using MyExtensions  чтобы всем этим пользоваться

Comment: Я предлагаю, чтобы TryParse возвращал Nullable<int>
Просто Parse мне не нравится т.к. он кидает эксепшн, что довольно дорого.

Comment: во-первых, Nullable<T> и T - это два разных типа, а во-вторых, TryParse появился гораздо раньше Nullable<T>.

Более того, 

>он кидает эксепшн, что довольно дорого

что вы делаете такого, что выброс исключения для вас дорог? (уверен, ничего). Это скорее всего говорит о том, что вы занимаетесь ненужной оптимизацией. То же самое касается экономии  4 байт для TryParse. Если так сильно неудобен синтаксис - можно написать свой метод и с помощью расширений добавить его к int

Comment: В данной конкретном случае с int Nullable<int>, но вообще да Nullable<T>. Tryxxx и int? появились со 2 фреймворка.
У меня вопрос не о скорости работы, а, скорее, о читаемости кода.

Comment: Не очень понятны ваши трудности с читаемостью, точнее, чем ваш вариант будет более читаем? В текущей реализации нужно так:

    int res;
    int anotherVal = Int32.TryParse(myString, out res) ? res : -1;

В вашей, насколько понимаю, так: 

    int anotherVal = Int32.TryParse("10").HasValue ? Int32.TryParse("10").Value : -1;

Читаемость пожалуй еще хуже, при этом Int32.TryParse нужно выполнить уже дважды (либо опять-таки завести "ненужную" переменную. И потом, еще раз повторю, если вам так важна читаемость, то почему бы не написать свой метод, решающий эту проблему?

Comment: Ок. Вот мой метод tryparse
[code]
public static int? MyTryParse(string value)
{
  try
    {return Int32.Parse(value);}
    catch (ArgumentNullException)
    { return null; }
    catch (FormatException)
    { return null; }
}
[/code]
Тогда использовать его можно
[code]
ViewBag.Value = HomeController.MyTryParse("10") ?? -1;
[/code]
Можно в if на null проверять, без всяких лишних переменных ради переменных. Но мне приходится использовать Parse, ловить исключения, глотать их, разрабы фреймворка могла все сделать без лишних расходов.

Comment: >Но мне приходится использовать Parse, ловить исключения, глотать их, разрабы фреймворка могла все сделать без лишних расходов

@Vasya_P вы слишком преувеличиваете масштаб трагедии. Я обновил ответ, взгляните, думаю, вам подойдет
З.Ы. Для выделения кода нужно перед каждой его строкой писать 4 пробела